# How to compose a Shout Chorus

Tags: theory, chords, composition

How do you compose a [Shout Chorus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refrain#Shout_chorus)?
I don´t know how to start and I need to compose one for Wine and Roses.

Comment: The wiki link in your question gives a list of procedures you can use. Have you tried them?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it seems that if you've already got a chorus composed, then the shout chorus is just a modification of the chorus that is characterized by having more "energy". "Energy" can be amplified through, as your article states, having all the instruments play louder, with more fills, and sometimes all together (but sometimes building off of each other). Additionally, I'd say that some other effects could be inverting chords higher, maybe having the key go higher, and sharper attacks than previous choruses. I'm not sure what Wine and Roses is, but I hope this isn't too late.

One common element in a lot of shout choruses (chorii?) is a unison delivery of the melody, and sometimes they do this cool "break" thing (there's probably a better word) where every performer anticipates the melody, creating a "break" in the middle of a phrase.

Comment: The Days of Wine and Roses, Henry Mancini.

Comment: Oh. Well, I don't know that song, but these will probably help in general.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you've written your chart by now, @ahuhm!   May we see what you ended up with?

Here's a good resource.   Followed by a possible approach to 'Wine and Roses', blatantly stealing Tom Kubis' idea :-)

http://jazzarrangingclass.com/how-to-write-a-big-band-shout-chorus-part-1/

[image]